# What is My friend's (not so) new interest

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

A friend of mine is an English teacher, but he's always enjoyed listening to the sound of music in the classroom while he works, so I'm thinking he's looking for a change of job soon. Maybe these notes I found on his desk will help me figure out his (not so) new interest?

e <s>e</s>ay <s>i</s>e r w - <s>i</s>ea

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not so convinced your friend actually *is* looking for a new occupation - I think he's pretty much an English teacher through and through, although he really does like...

> ...[*The Sound of Music*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_of_Music), doesn't he?!

He has a song stuck in his head, for sure. Namely:

> [*Do-Re-Mi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-Re-Mi) from the 1959 musical, in which the Von Trapp children are introduced to the [Solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge) method of teaching musical notes via a chorus which goes:
>
>  **Do**, a deer, a female deer
>  **Re**, a drop of golden sun
>  **Mi**, a name I call myself
>  **Fa**, a long, long way to run
>  **So**, a needle pulling thread
>  **La**, a note to follow So
>  **Ti**, a drink with jam and bread
>  That will bring us back to Do (oh, oh, oh...)

What your teacher friend has gone and done, however, is...

> ...treated this as a spelling test and **corrected all the spellings**!
>
>  e = Add 'e' to 'Do' to make '**Doe**' (a deer, a female deer);
>  <s>e</s>ay = Remove 'e' from 'Re' and add 'ay' to make '**Ray**' (a drop of golden sun);
>  <s>i</s>e = Replace 'i' in 'Mi' with 'e' to make '**Me**' (a name I call myself);
>  r = Add 'r' to 'Fa' to make '**Far**' (a long, long way to run);
>  w = Add 'w' to 'So' to make '**Sow**' (a needle pulling thr- Wait, a sec...);
>  - = Do nothing to '**La** - that one's fine!
>  <s>i</s>ea = Remove 'i' from 'Ti' and add 'ea' to make '**Tea**' (a drink with jam and bread);
>   = A musical repeat symbol, because that *brings us back* to Do!

Only one problem though...

> He's made a spelling error of his own. 'Sow' should be spelled 'Sew' in a needlecraft context. Perhaps he really should be looking for a different profession after all...!

Comment: I shouldn't write these on the train! You got it, well done. Do you think I should fix the mistake?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Ha, entirely up to you :) I think it adds character! (But if you do decide to fix it, I'll amend my answer also...)